# The time taken by Basha to complete each round of the circular track is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Akbar keeps running on a circular track with a uniform speed such that he completes one round 
every 40 seconds. On the same circular track Basha keeps running, but in the direction opposite to 
Akbar, with such uniform speed, that Akbar meets him every 15 seconds.

Comment: The statement of the problem is very clear, so much that one suspects you are quoting it verbatim.  Please put this problem into context for Readers so that they understand what question you need to ask about it.  Did you set up the problem in terms of "time take by Basha to complete each round"?  You should attempt an exercise before posting here and include your observations so that Readers can advance your studies more expeditiously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose the track length is $C$.

The speed of Akbar is $$v_a=\frac{\text{distance travelled by Akbar in a round}}{\text{time  taken}}=\ldots$$ (you can work out the rest yourself, leave it in $C$.)

The speed of Basha is $v_b$.

Assuming they start from the same place (which actually doesn't matter), you can think of it as they are $C$ units apart in a straight line.

So now you know that in the common time period $t_m=15 \text{ s}$, Akbar and Basha meet somewhere but their total distance is $C$. So you can form the equation using

$$\text{distance travelled by Akbar in $t_m$}+\text{distance travelled by Basha in $t_m$}=C$$

and solve for $v_b$.